# Finding a closest looking segment of data in another sequence

Tags: vector, signal-processing, similarity

I am doing image processing, in which I came across a situation, where I have to compare two vectors and find an instance of the smaller vector in the larger vector.

Say the two vectors are A: with 100 elements (or entries)
 and B; with 10 elements. B is a model and it may not be present exactly as it is' in the vector A. I can compare 10 elements at a time and find the difference. Ideal case is that the B is present somewhere and the difference is zero. Otherwise a minimum will result at some random location, and i am missing the location.

Please help me in giving an algorithm such that the i can find Bs' closest instance in A.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is the [cross-correlation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-correlation) function.The peak the the cross correlation of the two vectors will be the point were vector B is most similar to vector A.

You may want to get an explanation of how it is implemented in matlab [HERE](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/signal/ref/xcorr.html) as it gives an easier explanation of how this operation can be implemented in software.